# How to unit test an Angular directive with an Input?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I have the below directive which is added to an element using the `copy-to-clipboard` attribute, and copies the content of the attribute to the users clipboard on click:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[copy-to-clipboard]'
})
export class CopyToClipboardDirective {
  @Input('copy-to-clipboard') public payload: string;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.payload) {
      return;
    }

    const listener = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      const clipboard = e.clipboardData;
      clipboard.setData('text', this.payload.toString());
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    document.addEventListener('copy', listener, false);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.removeEventListener('copy', listener, false);
  }
}
```

And my unit test is setup as the following:

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {CopyToClipboardDirective} from './copy-to-clipboard.directive';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<input [copy-to-clipboard]="'this is the passed string'" role="button" type="button">`
})
class MockCopyToClipboardComponent {}

fdescribe('Directive: CopyToClipboard', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MockCopyToClipboardComponent>;
  let component: MockCopyToClipboardComponent;
  let element;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CopyToClipboardDirective, MockCopyToClipboardComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockCopyToClipboardComponent);
    element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should run the copy command', () => {
    spyOn(document, 'execCommand');
    element.querySelector('input').click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm getting an error back to say that the expected condition never occurs. I'm trying to set up the test to confirm that the `document.execCommand` has in fact been called, and not sure how I can confirm that the copied value matches that of the input string?

Answer (score 2):

I run your test and found that the value of `CopyToClipboardDirective#payload` was never set. You can make this work by placing `fixture.detectChanges()` at the end of the `beforeEach` function.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CopyToClipboardDirective, MockCopyToClipboardComponent]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MockCopyToClipboardComponent);
    element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // >>>>>> ADD this line 
});

it('should run the copy command', () => {
    spyOn(document, 'execCommand');
    element.querySelector('input').click();
    // fixture.detectChanges(); // >>>>>> REMOVE this line
    expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy');
});
```

To check, what text was copied to the clipboard, you can try to read it back using [`Clipboard#readText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText). Since `readText` returns a `Promise`, you need to deal with its asynchronous nature. The following example used the `done` function to do this.

```
it('should run the copy command', (done) => {
    spyOn(document, 'execCommand');
    element.querySelector('input').click();
    expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy');

    element.querySelector('input').focus();
    navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(t => {
      expect(t).toBe('this is the passed string');
      done();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      fail(err);
    });
});
```